# Linking Matlab shared library into Qt (Windows)

Tags: qt, matlab, windows-xp, .lib

I want to use Matlab's C API within QT (http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f39876.html#bsfvqhp-1) under Windows for opening a .mat file. In my .pro file I have included 
`INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\extern\include"` 
which works fine (the code compiles). But when trying to link the libmat.lib file (I have read the .dll files cannot be linked directly) using 
`LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\extern\lib\win32\microsoft" -llibmat` 
the application crashes on execution. The error given says `[file].exe exited with code -1073741515`

I'm neither a QT nor a Windows expert but for this project I am forced to use both (I guess it would be easier to fix this in GNU/Linux) so any help would be appreciated. Using Windows XP, QT version 4.7.0 with Qt Creator 2.0.1, and Matlab R2010b.

The last output from the compiler just in case it is useful:
`g++ -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -mthreads -Wl -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o debug/MainUI.exe debug/main.o debug/maingui.o debug/matparser.o debug/matutils.o debug/moc_maingui.o  -L'c:/Qt/2010.05/qt/lib' -lmingw32 -lqtmaind "-LC:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\extern\lib\win32\microsoft" -llibmat -lQtGuid4 -lQtCored4`

Comment: Which compiler are you using and do you know which compiler was used to build the Matlab library? Also, can you expand on what you mean when you say you "have read the .dll files cannot be linked directly"?

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure about which compiler does QT use in Windows (I guess win32-g++ since the build system is mingw32-make) and I have no idea about the compiler used to build the Matlab library. When I'm saying that DLL files cannot be linked directly I mean that the .lib files should be used instead in the configuration file (.pro).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I understand what you mean now about linking directly. I've added an answer that suggests what _might_ be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested building a simple C program that uses the [MAT-File Interface Library](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/read-and-write-matlab-mat-files-in-c-c-and-fortran.html) with no problems. The example file is located in: [`matlabroot/examples/eng_mat/matcreat.c`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/list-of-examples.html). I am compiling using [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) on a Windows XP 32-bit machine. Here is the Makefile I used:

```
# root directory of MATLAB installation
MATLABROOT="/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2010b"

.PHONY : all clean run

all: matcreat

matcreat:
    gcc ${MATLABROOT}/extern/examples/eng_mat/matcreat.c -o matcreat \
        -I${MATLABROOT}/extern/include \
        -L${MATLABROOT}/extern/lib/win32/microsoft -llibmat -llibmx

clean:
    rm -rf matcreat *.exe *.mat

run:
    # UNIX uses LD_LIBRARY_PATH to find libs at runtime, Windows/MinGW uses PATH
    @PATH=${MATLABROOT}/bin/win32:"${PATH}" ./matcreat
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. I can't try your code since I completely abandoned the Matlab solution in favour of creating and parsing my own binary format. If anybody can try it please do and give Amro a positive vote.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the Matlab library will have been compiled with MSVC and since you say you are compiling your own code with MingW I would imagine the two are incompatible.

Have a look at [the MingW page on mixing compilers](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MixingCompilers) for more information.